# LibreOffice Calc, How to add a menu at file open and remove on file close

Tags: macros, openoffice-calc, libreoffice

I have a few (recorded) macro's in LibreOffice Calc. I created a menu item and a few toolbar items for these macro's, but they are visible all the time. Since these macro's are specific for this spreadsheet ONLY (stored inside the spreadsheet), I would like to add the menu items "on-file-open", dim the added menu "on-file-not-active" and remove the menu items "on-file-close".

Inside MS Excel, this is relatively easy, and I have done that many times, but I have not been able to find the LibreOffice equivalents of Excel's On-Open, On-Close, etc.

Furthermore, When I try to record "adding the menu items", nothing (specific to adding the menu) is recorded.

I've been using (and writing code for) Excel for about 20 years, but I am new to the LibreOffice macro language style.

I wonder where I can find examples of both the "on open/close/active" and how to add/remove a menu tree in a LibreOffice macro.